# Can bazel print a hierarchy of the build rules?

Tags: bazel, build-rules

Bazel rules can compose other bazel rules. 
For example:

```
def cpp_library(name,deps=[]):

    explicit_cpp_file = name + ".cpp"
    explicit_hpp_file = name + ".hpp"

    native.cc_library(
        name = name,
        srcs = [explicit_cpp_file],
        hdrs = [explicit_hpp_file],
        deps = deps,
    )
```

Here we see that the `cpp_library` uses `native.cc_library`.
**Is there a way to use a bazel query to print this relationship information?**

You can imagine the difficulty of wanting to know which rules are used by which other rules as a project grows in size and many rules are available.

Comment: One nitpick: rules (i.e. Starlark rules) can't compose other rules directly, but macros can compose rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this information through `bazel query` with `--output`. `--output build` will show the rules after macros have been run. `--output graph` will show the relationships between rules, e.g.

```
bazel query //some/package --output graph | xdot
```

(or e.g. `| dot -Tpng > /tmp/dep.png`)

See https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/query.html#output-formats